# Single Word for "removing unused stuff"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a single word for the term:

"removing unused stuff".

#### Edit:

To be used in the following context:

I am to use this word for a program that does some cleaning of useless stuff. But I want to avoid software lingo like erase/delete kind of things as they are already day to day usage for my audience.

I am looking for connotations that make it sound more funny or creative.

So rather than using XYZcleaner or XYZdeleter, something more fancy.

Comment: Prune? Clean? Trim?

Comment: Prune is also my choice

Comment: Any context for this question?

Comment: @JimiOke: added context as asked for

Comment: I favour *eBay*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Purge.

As noted in the comments, "prune" works. But since it refers mainly to gardening, it conveys a sense of trimming back useful things that are overgrown.

I think this conveys clearing out things that aren't useful and getting down to basic essentials.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/purge

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest one very universal word *eliminate.* Anyway, there could be many possibilities since *stuff* can stand for several meanings. For example, if the *stuff* is information, then *erase/delete*.

Comment: here my stuff is information but I want to stay away from technical terms like erase/delete as they are in daily use for my audience and doesn't sound exciting.  Woudn't 'eliminate' means complete destruction rather than destruction of unused stuff ? thnks

Answer (score 2):

'declutter' is frequently used if it is getting unnecessary stuff out of your space.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the stuff is information. You can "**drop/dismiss**" some (unused) information
>   and keep (retain) others.

Answer (score 1):

*Filter* could be used in a figurative sense.

> Filter (verb):
>
> : to pass (something, such as a gas or liquid) through a filter to remove something unwanted
>
> : to remove (something unwanted) by using a filter
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filter))